# Laravel 5 GET is working but POST method is not working

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-5, get, routes

I am new to Laravel and I am facing a weird issue. In the routes I am calling a function through POST and GET method.

GET returns data but POST doesn't. Here is my simple code:

For POST

```
Route::post('register', function() {
    echo 'we are here';
});
```

For GET:

```
Route::get('register', function() {
    echo 'we are here';
});
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting? And how are you making post request?

Comment: so what does post method gives. any error message.

Comment: Friends, I am using a firefox plugin "HTTP Requester"
There I am giving parameters and then POST data

Comment: Here is screenshot of POST 
  http://prntscr.com/b22e3m
And here is screenshot of GET
  http://prntscr.com/b22ehp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to include a CSRF token on every request (except GET).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: Sounds something. So how would I add it in routes ?

Comment: Add `_token` with the CSRF token to the input request.

Comment: Do you mean like this ?
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@index', '_token');

Comment: No. Add `_token` just like you have `firstname`, `lastname` in your request.

Comment: Ok now this is my URL
http://testsite.com/dev/api/v2/register?_token=6486
Have I written correct ?

Comment: No. You need to provide the actual CSRF token. /register?_token= c0AvTsPSOFzS2agssRbHnm9pIdSz35eeyNq0uZHM&firstname=Zain&lastname=SMJ

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Your form will look like this

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

   ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware will be able to validate the request. To generate a hidden CSRF token field, you may use the csrf_field helper function:

// Vanilla PHP:

```
<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
```

// Blade Template Syntax:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

The csrf_field helper function generates the following HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

You do not need to manually verify the CSRF token on POST, PUT, or DELETE requests. The  VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web middleware group, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the web without ajax, you can check out and use the above answers or use

```
<form action="">
   @csrf
   ...
</form>
```

If you need to call this URL via ajax request
**Step 1**: Add CSRF token inside your meta tag (), you can specify inside your main.blade.php file (layout)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Step 2: Add **X-CSRF-TOKEN** header inside your ajax request

```
    var APP_URL = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!}
    $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            data:({search:input}),
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: ''+APP_URL+'/register',
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
               alert('error');
            },
        });
```

Thank you!